# how to share text on facebook using javascript?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, facebook, cordova

I am developing an android application using PhoneGap. I need to  post text on Facebook.
I know that in Twitter it can be done through below code .

```
var mediaSource = "http://twitter.com/home?status={TITLE}";
mediaSource = mediaSource.replace('{TITLE}',"Text to be share in Twitter");

window.location = mediaSource;
```

Is there any similar method to post text in Facebook?

Edit : 
     I got a partial solution from this [egrappler](http://www.egrappler.com/jquery-social-media-share-plugin-jsshare/)

my code as follows :

```
var mediaSource = "http://www.facebook.com/share.php?u={ADDRESS}";
mediaSource=mediaSource.replace('{ADDRESS}',encodeURIComponent('http://www.google.com'));
window.location = mediaSource;
```

from the above code I  am able to  share only the link in facebook wall. I need to share text with the link . The text should be sent through the code along with the website link.
Please help me to sort out this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a phonegap plugin you can post text on Facebook. This plugin is called [Share](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/Share)

Then adding .java and .js files to your project, all will be done!